# Lambda issue while passing on method

Tags: ruby, lambda

In my application has status array which is something like this

```
 status = ['success','failure','warning']
```

For example, lambda to process status array like this

```
 print_status = lambda { |stat| puts stat }
```

When I'm trying to pass lambda on status's each method, I got an error which says "ArugmentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)"

```
 status.each(print_status)
```

any one help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue happen due to block and proc mismatch. In your status each method expects block not proc. Ideal solution to convert proc to block is that "&"

```
 status.each(&print_status)
```

Hope this code may help you to solve your issue

Comment: And if you do not want to convert it to a proc a slightly uglier syntax would be status.each{|stat|print_status.call(stat)}

Comment: This is the solution, you save my time :), thanks Veerasekar. hirolau thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @main_ka Is it useful?